# How to plot multiple series/lines in a time series using plotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, plotly, timeserieschart

I have a time series of several years that I need to plot mm/dd on the x-axis and multiple years on the y-axis using plot_ly. I have generated a sample data here:

```
date<-seq(as.Date("2010-11-22"),as.Date("2016-05-26"),by ="days")
sales = runif(2013, 2000, 6000)
df = data.frame(date,sales)
```

I plotted this data and get this:

```
plot_ly(df,x= ~date) %>% add_lines(y = ~sales,color=I("red"))
```

[image]

Now, I tried to plot multiple y-axis using `plot_ly`:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~date) %>% add_lines(y = ~sales, 
df$date <= "2010-12-31",color=I("red")) %>% 
             add_lines(y = ~sales, df$date <= "2013-12-31" & 
             df$date >= 2013-01-01, color = I("green"))
```

but I got wrong plot:

[image]

What's the mistake in that?

I want the plot like this:

[image]

Comment: you mean multiple series (instead of y axis); right?

Comment: just like the last image, mm/dd on x-axis vs sales of each year with different colors.

Answer (score 3):

To create different lines on the same graph we have to split the `df` in group with `plotly::group_by`. In your case this is achieved using `lubridate` to split by year:

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
date <- seq(as.Date("2010-11-22"), as.Date("2016-05-26"), by = "days")
# Add some variations to distinguish lines
sales <-  runif(2013, 10, 20) + year(date) * 5 + yday(date) / 5
df <-  data.frame(date, sales)


df %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~ yday(date)) %>% 
  add_lines(y = ~ sales, 
            color = ~ factor(year)
            )
```

[image]

Comment: can you plot mm/dd on the x-axis instead of day number?

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607811/r-formatting-axis-and-titles-on-plotly-plots-time-series thanks!